# Seeking Guidance for DXF File Display in Web Browser

Tags: dxf

I am currently working on a project that involves the generation and display of DXF files in a web browser. During my research, I came across library "@tarikjabiri/dxf," which seemed promising for my requirements.

I have successfully utilized your library to generate DXF files, and the generated files display perfectly in the AutoCAD 2023 Windows application. However, I am encountering challenges when attempting to view these DXF files in a web browser. I have explored a couple of libraries for this purpose, specifically:

dxf-viewer (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dxf-viewer): This library, unfortunately, does not render shapes that are drawn using the hatch feature from the DXF files.

three-dxf-viewer (https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-dxf-viewer): This library, on the other hand, is unable to open DXF files that have been generated using the "@tarikjabiri/dxf" library.

I am reaching out to seek guidance and expertise in addressing this issue. My ultimate goal is to display DXF files within a web browser while ensuring that shapes created with hatching are accurately rendered.